# PKCS12 CERTIFICATE ERROR

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

I am receiving the following exception regarding PKCS12 certificate
1. unwrapping private key
2. illegal key size
The following is my actual exception which I received.

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key -                java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.unwrapKey(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
at Signatures.signPdfFirstTime(Signatures.java:103)
at Signatures.main(Signatures.java:229)
```

This is my actual code on which I am working

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CertificateInfo;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CertificateVerification;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalDigest;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.CryptoStandard;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.VerificationException;

public class Signatures {

    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String ORIGINAL = "C://Proj1//hello.pdf";
    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String SIGNED1 = "C://Proj1//signature_1.pdf";
    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String SIGNED2 = "C://Proj1//signature_2.pdf";
    /** Info after verification of a signed PDF */
    public static String VERIFICATION = "results/part3/chapter12/verify.txt";
    /** The resulting PDF */
    public static String REVISION = "results/part3/chapter12/revision_1.pdf";

    /**
     * A properties file that is PRIVATE.
     * You should make your own properties file and adapt this line.
     */
    public static String PATH = "C://Proj1//keystore.properties";
    /** Some properties used when signing. */
    public static Properties properties = new Properties();
    /** One of the resources. */
    public static final String RESOURCE = "C://Proj1//logo.jpeg";

    /**
     * Creates a PDF document.
     * @param filename the path to the new PDF document
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
        document.close();
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     */
    public void signPdfFirstTime(String src, String dest)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        //String path = properties.getProperty("PRIVATE");
        char[] str="mysecret".toCharArray();

        String path="C://Proj1//keystore.p12";
        //String keystore_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
        String key_password="C://Proj1//keystore.propertise";
        // String key_password = properties.getProperty("PASSWORD");
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12","BC"); 
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), str);

        String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        // reader and stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
        // appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper .getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setImage(Image.getInstance(RESOURCE));
        appearance.setReason("I've written this.");
        appearance.setLocation("Foobar");
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1,    "first");
        // digital signature
        ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates a PDF file src with the file dest as result
     * @param src the original PDF
     * @param dest the resulting PDF
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws DocumentException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     */
    public void signPdfSecondTime(String src, String dest)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String path = "C://Proj1//.keystore";
        String keystore_password = "ram007";
        String key_password = "ram0075";
        String alias = "agreeya";
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(path), keystore_password.toCharArray());
        PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, key_password.toCharArray());
        Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
        // reader / stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0', null, true);
        // appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper
                .getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setReason("I'm approving this.");
        appearance.setLocation("Foobar");
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(160, 732, 232, 780), 1, "second");
        // digital signature
        ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256", "BC");
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);

    }

    /**
     * Verifies the signatures of a PDF we've signed twice.
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void verifySignatures() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
        FileInputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(properties.getProperty("ROOTCERT"));
        X509Certificate cert1 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("cacert", cert1);
        FileInputStream is2 = new FileInputStream("resources/encryption/foobar.cer");
        X509Certificate cert2 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(is2);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("foobar", cert2);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(VERIFICATION));
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SIGNED2);
        AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
        ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            out.println("Signature name: " + name);
            out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
            out.println("Document revision: " + af.getRevision(name) + " of " + af.getTotalRevisions());
            PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);
            Calendar cal = pk.getSignDate();
            Certificate[] pkc = pk.getCertificates();
            out.println("Subject: " + CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields(pk.getSigningCertificate()));
            out.println("Revision modified: " + !pk.verify());
            List<VerificationException> errors = CertificateVerification.verifyCertificates(pkc, ks, null, cal);
            if (errors.size() == 0)
                out.println("Certificates verified against the KeyStore");
            else
                out.println(errors);    
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * Extracts the first revision of a PDF we've signed twice.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void extractFirstRevision() throws IOException {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SIGNED2);
        AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(REVISION);
        byte bb[] = new byte[1028];
        InputStream ip = af.extractRevision("first");
        int n = 0;
        while ((n = ip.read(bb)) > 0)
            os.write(bb, 0, n);
        os.close();
        ip.close();
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param    args    no arguments needed
     * @throws DocumentException 
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws IOException, DocumentException, GeneralSecurityException {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(PATH));
        Signatures signatures = new Signatures();
        signatures.createPdf(ORIGINAL);
        signatures.signPdfFirstTime(ORIGINAL, SIGNED1);
        signatures.signPdfSecondTime(SIGNED1, SIGNED2);
        //      signatures.verifySignatures();
        //    signatures.extractFirstRevision();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the p12 container in question? I.e. is it a test key?

Comment: yes it is a test key created by the java keytool

Answer (score 4):

Did you read [Digital signatures for PDF documents](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures)?

I quote:

> Don’t panic if you get an `InvalidKeyException` 
>   saying that the key size is invalid. Due to import control restrictions by the governments of a few 
>   countries, the encryption libraries shipped by default with the Java SDK restrict the length, and as a 
>   result the strength, of encryption keys. 
>   If you want to avoid this problem, you need to replace the default security JARs in your Java 
>   installation with the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files. 
>   These JARs are available for download from http://java.oracle.com/ in eligible countries.

Did you install the Java Cryptography Extension?